# How to clear previous data in socket buffer?

Tags: file, sockets, server

I am sending data over to my server which writes the received data back to the client and the data also gets stored in a text file on the server.

I have this problem: if the length of the sent message is smaller than previously sent messages, the extra characters get added to the current message.

For example if I send "hello" first and then I send "all", the stored messages on the file are:

```
hello
alllo
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>    //write

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , read_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char client_message[2000];

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    //accept connection from an incoming client
    client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&$
    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Connection accepted");

    //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(client_sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
        //Send the message back to client
        write(client_sock , client_message , strlen(client_message));
        //append the received data at the end of the file
        FILE *f = fopen("data.txt", "a");
        if (f == NULL){
                printf("Error opening file!\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        char *text = client_message;
        fprintf(f, "%s\n", text);
        fclose(f);
        //clear socket
    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So I think I need to clear the buffer after writing to the file, but I'm not sure how to do this. I would greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usual problem. Incorrect copy loop. Ignoring the receive length, and assuming the data fills the buffer and/or is null-terminated.

It should look like this in general:

```
while ((count = recv(source_sd, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0)) > 0)
{
    write(target_fd, buffer, count);
    // or
    fwrite(buffer, 1, count, target_file);
}
```

And opening and closing a file every time around the loop is pretty poor.

Nothing to do with clearing the socket buffer. It is clear after the loop.